# Carregar imagem após item selecionado

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Na minha aplicação o usuário define um diretório raiz. Após definir a raiz existe a listagem de arquivos presentes no diretório. Quando o arquivo for selecionado existe um outro diretório onde existe uma imagem com o mesmo nome do arquivo. Eu quero que ao selecionar o arquivo ele exiba a imagem referente ao arquivo. Eu pesquisei o componente `p:graphicImage` mas não achei um bom exemplo. Vi usando a `library="images"` porém ele só reconhece as imagens que estão na pasta resources/images. Eu pensei que se eu pudesse alterar a localização padrão desta library apontando pra minha pasta de imagens eu poderia resolver o problema. Gostaria de saber se essa seria a melhor solução? Ou se me ajudem a resolver este problema de outra maneira.

No momento a página está assim:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel header="Informações dos Itens">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Diretório Raiz Origem: " for="diretorioRaizOrigem" />
            <p:inputText id="diretorioRaizOrigem" value="#{questItemController.questItem.diretorioRaizOrigem}">
                <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" immediate="true" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel for="itemOrigem" value="Item Origem" />
            <p:autoComplete id="itemOrigem" value="#{questItemController.questItem.nomeItemOrigem}"
                completeMethod="#{questItemController.listarItensDiretorioOrigem}" dropdown="true" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean}"
                itemValue="#{bean}" effect="bounce" forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="3">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{questItemController.itemChange()}" update="itemDestino,imagem" process="@this" />
            </p:autoComplete>
            <p:outputLabel value="Diretório Raiz de Destino" for="diretorioRaizDestino" />
            <p:inputText id="diretorioRaizDestino" value="#{questItemController.questItem.diretorioRaizDestino}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Item Destino" for="itemDestino" />
            <p:inputText id="itemDestino" value="#{questItemController.questItem.nomeItemDestino}" />
            <p:graphicImage id="imagem" value="" rendered="#{questItemController.mostrarImagem}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: coloca o código do questItemController também.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma Servlet que lê o arquivo de imagem em um diretório de acordo com um parâmetro na url e depois passar como parâmetro na url do graphicImage;

```
urlImagem = "/imagem?nome=nome-da-imagem";

<p:graphicImage id="imagem" url="#{questItemController.urlImagem}" rendered="#{questItemController.mostrarImagem}"/>
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/imagem")
public class LogoMarcaServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("diretorio/das/imagens/" + request.getParameter("nome"));
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.write(data);
        response.setContentType("image/png"); 
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        response.setBufferSize(out.size());    

        out.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }

}
```